# Examples of open/closed boundaries wrt PDEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, plane-geometry

Consider this line: `y=2x, x is any real number`

According to a Finnish math book, this line is "closed on a plane". I tried to look up what it means to be closed or open on a plane and I couldn't really find a specific definition anywhere. [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668657/what-is-meant-by-an-open-boundary-when-specifying-boundary-conditions-of-pdes) something seemingly related. According to that source, a close boundary is confined to a finite surface or volume. I don't know how you take the surface of a line. Is it zero? Does this make it "finite", even though the line extends to infinity in both directions?

Can you provide examples to illustrate what it means for something to be "open/closed on a plane"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concepts "open" and "close" belong to topology. A set it's closed if it's equal to its closure. The closure of a set is the set of points having for any neighbourhood (neighbourhood=any open set containing the point) a not empty intersection with the initial set. You can consider a closed set intuitively as a set containing it's border. The contrary for an open one.

A line in the plane is a closed set because it is its own border (intuitively, but the definition works). An open set in the plane is e.g. $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x^2+y^2<1\}$ being the border $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$ not belonging to $A$

But in the link you give, the concepts "open" and "closed" are used with a different meaning. The finish book is referring to the topological, the link to analysis.